# Powershell if number of digits = 5 then remove 3rd digit

Tags: powershell, numbers, digit

I've got a list of numbers that is mostly 4 digits. I need to use this 4 digit code to identify a URL used in another part of my script. I want to evaluate if $wnl = 5 digits, then remove the 3rd digit.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (($wnl | Measure-Object -Character).Characters -eq 5) {
  $str = ($wnl.ToString()).Remove(2,1)
  return $str
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"hello" | get-member` is a way you can find out what you can do with strings.

To find out more about any of these methods, you can google `string.membername .NET`

I'm not sure if your list of numbers is ints or strings.  ints convert nicely to strings, so it doesn't really matter.

```
if ($yourvar.ToString().Length -eq 5) {$newvar = $yourvar.ToString().Remove(2,1)}
```